# The location of the latest released source about wso2 product

Tags: svn, wso2

Recentely I am trying to build the latest released version of DSS, BPS, ESB, BRS, I check out source from the location "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/turing-chunk07/".

Question 1:
Is it the location of latest released source of wso2?

Question 2:
What is the different between the soucrce in "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/", " "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/" and "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/"?

Question 3:
I noticed that BRS is still on the base of carbon 4.0.3, I want to know when it will be updated to base on 4.2.0?

Question 4:
If I need to only build DSS, BPS, ESB, BRS, what is the best method to do it?

Question 5:
BRS2.0.0 is compatible with the other 3 products(DSS 3.1.1, BPS 3.2.0, ESB 4.8.1)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be directed to the maintainers of this particular project

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will send this link to the maintainers of wso2.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below details add some values:

-You can get more info  about releases map to source code versions  from  http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

-you can see source for each product once you go into each product document and see section "Build from source section" , for example https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Building+from+Source